# Can a private method in controller be decorated with action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have something in my controller which looks like this.

```
[AuthorizeActivity(Module = Abc.Abc, Action = ActionModules.Edit)]
public JsonResult UpdateBudget(BudgetModel budget)
{
    return UpdateBudget(budget, budget.CustomerId);
}

[AuthorizeAbc]
private JsonResult UpdateBudget(BudgetModel budget, int id)
{}
```

I have a `AuthorizeActivity` which is a AuthorizeAttribute, which checks if the specified module and action is allowed for the logged in user.

The `AuthorizeAbc` mentioned on the private method is not getting called.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: can you paste your ajax request here?

Comment: Post the code for your `AuthorizeAbc` as well please.

Comment: No, or perhaps more appropriately, yes, but it won't do anything. Private methods are not usable as actions, so they'd never be routed to, and thus would not participate in any of the events the action filter lets you tie into.